# Error while using WWW::Mechanize in Perl to open a Webpage

Tags: perl, perl-module, www-mechanize

I am trying to open a web page in Perl using WWW::Mechanize module. The code for the same is as follows:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
$m->get($url);
print "$m->content()";
```

When i run this code i get an error like this:
Error GETing http://www.google.com :Can't connect to www.google.com:80.
What could be the reason for such an error and how can I change my code so that it opens up the webpage specified in the URL.?

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 problems :

1. the line `print "$m->content()";` should be written `print $m->content();` : you will get `WWW::Mechanize=HASH(0xeca870)->content()` otherwise.
2. it seems that you have a network or software problem: the rest of your code works.

Comment: I changed that. Still the same error. Is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: Do your PC can browse the web ? Are you sure the terminal is not in any kind of ssh remote session or such ? Don't you have any proxy running ?

Comment: My PC can browse the Web. I am using the strawberry perl terminal. I dont have any proxy running on my web browser. When i changed url  to 'http://www.cat.com' it worked fine. Giving any other URL created the error. Do you think it could be due to the port being occupied?

Comment: the google port 80 is clearly occupied, but there's tons of hardware in mountain view, so I think the problem is not on the google side but somewhere between your environment and the first network gateway. Proxy, firewall, malicious software... Dunno !